# Error making a request in STS to get Session Token

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to make a request on the STS API from Amazon AWS with the following code:

`

```
public class getSTS { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
String awsAccessKey = "";     
String awsSecretKey = ""; 
String region = "us-east-1";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Version", "2011-06-15");
    map.put("Action", "AssumeRole");
    map.put("RoleArn", "arn:aws:iam::**************:role/Funcao");
    map.put("DurationSeconds", "3600");
    map.put("RoleSessionName", "AmazonSeller");

    URL endpointUrl;
    try {
        endpointUrl = new URL("https://sts.amazonaws.com/?" +    AWS4SignerBase.getCanonicalizedQueryString(map));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse service endpoint: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader(endpointUrl, "GET", "sts", region);
    String authorization = signer.computeSignature(headers, map, AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256, awsAccessKey,
            awsSecretKey);


    headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
    String response = HttpUtils.invokeHttpRequest(endpointUrl, "GET", headers, null);
    System.out.println(response);
    }
}`
```

But in the response i got an error:

`<Error>`

`<Type>Sender</Type>`

`<Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>`

`<Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message>`

`</Error>`

What is the problem with my code?

I tried a few alternatives but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Service CLient for STS and call the **AssumeRole()** if you are using Java. Full example using AWS SDK for Java V2 and the **[STSClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sts/StsClient.html)**.

```
package com.example.sts;

// snippet-start:[sts.java2.assume_role.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.StsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.Credentials;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
// snippet-end:[sts.java2.assume_role.import]

/**
 * To make this code example work, create a Role that you want to assume.
 * Then define a Trust Relationship in the AWS Console. You can use this as an example:
 *
 * {
 *   "Version": "2012-10-17",
 *   "Statement": [
 *     {
 *       "Effect": "Allow",
 *       "Principal": {
 *         "AWS": "<Specify the ARN of your IAM user you are using in this code example>"
 *       },
 *       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
 *     }
 *   ]
 * }
 *
 *  For more information, see "Editing the Trust Relationship for an Existing Role" in the AWS Directory Service guide.
 *
 *  Also, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 *  For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class AssumeRole {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <roleArn> <roleSessionName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    roleArn - The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the role to assume (for example, rn:aws:iam::000008047983:role/s3role). \n"+
            "    roleSessionName - An identifier for the assumed role session (for example, mysession). \n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String roleArn = args[0];
        String roleSessionName = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        assumeGivenRole(stsClient, roleArn, roleSessionName);
        stsClient.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[sts.java2.assume_role.main]
    public static void assumeGivenRole(StsClient stsClient, String roleArn, String roleSessionName) {

        try {
            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(roleArn)
                .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                .build();

           AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
           Credentials myCreds = roleResponse.credentials();

           // Display the time when the temp creds expire.
           Instant exTime = myCreds.expiration();
           String tokenInfo = myCreds.sessionToken();

           // Convert the Instant to readable date.
           DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                   DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                           .withLocale( Locale.US)
                           .withZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() );

           formatter.format( exTime );
           System.out.println("The token "+tokenInfo + "  expires on " + exTime );

       } catch (StsException e) {
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }
   // snippet-end:[sts.java2.assume_role.main]
}
```